# Python: Replacing values in dictionary with array

Tags: python

I want to replace the value of first key of `list1` with the elements of `list2`. But the output with following code is:

## output

```
list[21, 21, 22, 22]
[{'a': array([[22, 22,  3]]), 'i': 'stop', 'c': array([7, 8, 9]), 'b': array([4, 5, 6])}, {'a': array([[1, 2, 3]]), 'i': 'stop', 'c': array([7, 8, 9]), 'b': array([4, 5, 6])}]
```

## my code

```
list1 = [{'a': array([(1,2,3)]), 'b': array([4,5,6]), 'i': 'stop', 'c': array([7,8,9])}, {'a': array([(1,2,3)]), 'b': array([4,5,6]), 'i': 'stop', 'c': array([7,8,9])}]


list2 = [ array([21, 22, 23]), array([25, 26, 27])]

list3=[]

for item in liste:
 for key,value in item.iteritems():    
    if key == 'a': 
      list3.append(value)

list4=[]
for i in range(len(g_a)):
    for j in range(len(list3)):
         
        list3[0][0][j] = g_a[0][i]
        list4.append(list3[0][0][j]) 
        
print list4
print list
```

I want to get this:

```
liste = [{'a': array([(21,22,23)]), 'b': array([4,5,6]), 'i': 'stop', 'c': array([7,8,9])}, {'a': array([(25,26,27)]), 'b': array([4,5,6]), 'i': 'stop', 'c': array([7,8,9])}]
```

Where is the error? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: where does `a` come from in `'a': array([(25,26,27)])`?

Comment: your code contains undefined identifiers that make it difficult to read, what is _liste_ ? I understand it's probably list1, but what is _g_a_? Consider rewriting your code to present a self-contained example.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to overwrite 'g_a'. g_a is the same like list2. In this code list1 has type list and contains two dictionaries. Any dictionary contains 4 keys(a,b,i,c) and values(the corresponding arrays). I want to replace only the values from key a with arrays from list 2 element wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a dict comprehension in python 2.7 with a one-liner:

```
[{k: d[k] if k != 'a' else list2[i] for k in d} for i, d in enumerate(list1)]
```

It gives:

```
[{'a': [21, 22, 23], 'i': 'stop', 'c': [7, 8, 9], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}, {'a': [25, 26, 27], 'i': 'stop', 'c': [7, 8, 9], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}]
```